# What's the correct regex for this?

Tags: python, regex

I want to catch `Sistemas Operativos` in `No aprobó ni está inscripto a Sistemas Operativos (Ord. 1150)`. The `(Ord. 1150)` is optional. It can appear, or not.

Mi first try was:
`No aprobó ni está inscripto a (.*)( \(Ord\. 1150\))?` but this returned `(u'Sistemas Operativos (Ord. 1150)', None)`.

So, what's the correct regex?

I'm using re in Python.

**Update:** I don't need to catch specifically the string 'Sistemas Operativos', that string is just an example. There could be any other string, but the context (`No aprobó ni está inscripto a .* (Ord.1150)`) will be always the same. See the comment by @DSM here.

Comment: Do you really need a regex? can't you just do `'Sistemas Operativos' in my_string`

Comment: Everyone seems to be thinking that you're just interested in knowing whether the phrase exists, but as I read you, you want "No aprobó ni está inscripto a THIS_IS_IN_ENGLISH (Ord. 1150)" to give "THIS_IS_IN_ENGLISH".  Am I right, or am I overreading?

Comment: @DSM You're right. I didn't express the question very well.

Comment: I've delete my answer now you've updated your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
No aprobó ni está inscripto a ([^()]*)( \(Ord\. 1150\))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O4DFB-mQP3jWNhNP)

Then you just need to do:

```
import re
myString = "No aprobó ni está inscripto a Sistemas Operativos (Ord. 1150)"
result = re.search('No aprobó ni está inscripto a ([^()]*)( \(Ord\. 1150\))?', myString)
course = result.group(1) # may have a trailing space, so maybe strip()
```

Comment: Sé que está mal, pero estoy obteniendo esos datos de una fuente que no controlo.

Comment: :( fixed the regex, though, to avoid the initial parenthesis

Comment: an alternative would be `No aprobó ni está inscripto a (.*?)( \(Ord\. 1150\))?`

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), meaning that it will consume as many characters as possible. Use `.*?` to make it lazy, thus allowing the subsequent `(Ord. 1150)` to match, and add a `$` to the end to make sure that the entirety of the text is read (in a sense, to counteract the effects of `.*?`).

```
>>> string = u'No aprobó ni está inscripto a Sistemas Operativos (Ord. 1150)'
>>> re.match(ur'No aprobó ni está inscripto a (.*?)( \(Ord\. 1150\))?$',
        string).groups()
(u'Sistemas Operativos', u' (Ord. 1150)')
```